# PCR limits of detection calculate method

Tags: bioinformatics, lab-techniques, pcr, biotechnology, methods

Is any standard method for use to gain PCR sensivity or limit of detection? my mean is not for RT-PCR or Real-Time or any other kind and just simple PCR. After making PCR product free of dNTP and Primers I have a microtube that contain 40ng/micro Liter dsDNA. My product size is 200bp. If I  should diluted it or any other standard acceptable method expain to me please.